Searching for '70s anthology of young writers' work, with stories about death during the sinking of Atlantis and a girl who sees a ghost in lamplight
I am looking for an anthologies of stories from young writers in the '70s.
It was an A4-sized hardback with a whitish cover and contained two particularly memorable stories.
One was a first person account of dying as Atlantis sunk. The other was about a girl who saw the ghost of a teenage girl in her bedroom by the light of a street lamp.
